# Self-deleting Executable

Tags: python, windows

I'm using Pyinstaller to create a single-file executable for a user. However, I want the user to be able to run this executable, then delete itself to leave their device 'clean'. Is there an elegant way of doing this in Python without resorting to batch files or uninstallers?

Just a little more specification, I'll be using python 3.4 and the users will be running Windows XP and on.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a python specific problem and has to do with how windows handles files for running executables. You may find [this information](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/self-deleting-executables) helpful..

Comment: I have read this already. I was looking for maybe some OS library calls that could be used at the end of my python file or something along those lines.

Comment: If you read it then you should understand that windows won't let you do what you want the way you want. Python can't circumvent the OS.